# Generate month end dates for last 12 months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need a method that generates an array containing the month end date for each of the past 12 months.  I've come up with the solution below.  It works, however, there's probably a more elegant way to solve this problem.  Any suggestions?  Is there a more efficient way to generate this array?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
require 'active_support/time'

...

def months
  last_month_end = (Date.today - 1.month).end_of_month
  months = [last_month_end]
  11.times do
    month_end = (last_month_end - 1.month).end_of_month
    months << month_end
  end
  months
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually when you want an array of things start thinking about `map`. While you're at it why not generalize such a method so you can get back any `n` months you wish:

```
def last_end_dates(count = 12)
  count.times.map { |i| (Date.today - (i+1).month).end_of_month }
end
```

```
>> pp last_end_dates(5)

[Sun, 30 Jun 2013,
 Fri, 31 May 2013,
 Tue, 30 Apr 2013,
 Sun, 31 Mar 2013,
 Thu, 28 Feb 2013]
```

Comment: Beautiful.  I love it.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I've played around with map before, but usually I'm trying to generate one array from another.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is why I still love ruby on rails. That is beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'active_support/time'

def months
  (1..12).map{|i| (Date.today - i.month).end_of_month}
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a specific method, this can be an option however:

```
(1..12).map { |i| (Date.today - i.month).end_of_month }
```

Nothing special, but does the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'active_support/time'
(1..12).map do |m|
  m.months.ago.end_of_month
end
```

Note, if you want correct order of months, you should also call reverse